# Apply loader to specific file

Tags: javascript, webpack

I'm following http://alexomara.com/blog/webpack-and-jquery-include-only-the-parts-you-need to bundle parts of jQuery using webpack.

```
// webpack.config.js
module.exports = {
    entry: './entry',
    output: {
        filename: 'bundle.js'
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            { 
                test: /jquery\/src\/selector\.js$/, 
                loader: 'amd-define-factory-patcher-loader' 
            }
        ]
    }
};
```

It turns out that `node_modules/jquery/src/selector.js` needs it own loader due to an AMD issue. But the loader is not being applied. I'm running under windows and maybe the regexp needs to be adjusted? I tried different expressions but no luck.

Any suggestions on how to debug?  New to webpack.

As suggested, I added:

```
profile: true,
stats: {
  reasons: true,
  chunkModules: true,
  chunkOrigins: true,
  modules: true,
  cached: true,
  cachedAssets: true,
  source: true,
  errorDetails: true,
  publicPath: true,
  excludeModules: [
    /e\.js/
  ]
```

Running `webpack --display-modules` yields

```
Hash: 4a092c0d4d9e158a9bd7
Version: webpack 1.10.1
Time: 970ms
    Asset    Size  Chunks             Chunk Names
   bundle.js  876 kB       0  [emitted]  main
[0] ./entry.js 529 bytes {0} [built]
   factory:13ms building:12ms = 25ms
...
[14] ./~/jquery/src/traversing/var/rneedsContext.js 110 bytes {0} [built]
   [0] 25ms -> [11] 161ms -> [13] 473ms -> factory:196ms building:3ms dependencies:1ms = 859ms
[15] ./~/jquery/src/selector.js 33 bytes {0} [built]
   [0] 25ms -> [16] 172ms -> factory:449ms building:180ms = 826ms
[16] ./~/jquery/src/manipulation.js 15 kB {0} [built]
   [0] 25ms -> factory:16ms building:156ms dependencies:443ms = 640ms
...
```

No errors.  Nothing of any real value.

Comment: Have you turned on all of the diagnostic messages in `config.stats`? That way you can see if the loader is being hit or not.

Comment: First time I have heard the term config.stats.  Are you talking about the profile option?  In any event, I'm fairly certain it's never being called.  In fact, I can put in a bogus name and still get no errors.

Comment: It's not well documented but here is an example [webpack stats config](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/blob/76230e4a4e4389e622c04ead1d79a7a7e122bd21/test/statsCases/chunks/webpack.config.js). Can you show an example of the outputted code for that module?

Comment: Wow.  A drive by down vote on a three year old question.  Some people just have way too much time on their hands.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Apparently Webpack does not normalize the path separators, so we must alter the regex to accommodate Windows-style directory separators.

Here is a platform-independent regex you can use, so it can work on both *nix systems and Windows.

```
{ test: /jquery[\\\/]src[\\\/]selector\.js$/, loader: 'amd-define-factory-patcher-loader' }
```

I've also updated the blog post to use this form. If you continue to have trouble, let me know!

**Full disclosure:** I wrote the blog post to which this question is referring, and happened to discover this question about it today.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you ever found the solution to this yourself however based on the comments section for the origional article:

http://alexomara.com/blog/webpack-and-jquery-include-only-the-parts-you-need/

It appears the correct regex when running on Windows is:

```
test: /jquery\\src\\selector\.js$/, loader: "amd-define-factory-patcher-loader"
```

Hope that helps!